# Android В цикле foreach переменная Null как так?

Tags: android, android-studio, foreach, null, for

Выдает ошибку во второй строке типа: on a null object reference

```
 for (Users.User user : listUsers) {
      long id = user.get_id();
```

Проверил в отладчике список listUsers - один элемент содержит. Но в цикл заходит второй раз и user = null. Я думал такого не может быть.

Да, как раз проект перенес на Android Studio 3 c версии 2.3 .
В Android Studio 2.3 код работает как часы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не заметил, что 2 элемента в списке было.